# Negaciones superfluas en oraciones con "hasta que": uso y aceptación

Tags: gramática, conjunciones

En español, la estructura de las oraciones con "hasta que" y "mientras" se puede complicar, dado que existen dos oraciones implicadas, y cada una puede ir en afirmativo o negativo. [Para más inri](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lj2jmID), si se usa "mientras que" hay que negar la oración que hace de causa. Así, tenemos (ejemplos de [Perogrullo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sh54Lwn)):

> Eso seguirá encendido hasta que se apague.
>   Eso seguirá encendido mientras no se apague.

O la versión con la oración inicial en negativo:

> Eso no se encenderá hasta que alguien le dé al botón.
>   Eso no se encenderá mientras nadie le dé al botón. <sub>(Negación cambiando "alguien" por "nadie".)</sub>

Sin embargo, tanto en la expresión oral como escrita se toma por costumbre arraigada el negar la segunda oración aunque no corresponda:

> Eso no se encenderá hasta que alguien no le dé al botón.

Por poner algunos ejemplos algo más literarios (negritas mías) que incurren en esta situación en la que sobra el "no" en "hasta que no":

> *Tardará en España todavía muchos años en implantarse totalmente y creo que **hasta que no** se fabriquen aquí seguirá siendo una cosa rara para la mayoría de la gente (de todas las edades).*
>
> ---
>
> *Pues no he de separarme de ti, ¡óyeme!, **hasta que no** los conozca.*
>
> ---
>
> *Entonces sí que a él se le concluyeron los arrestos, y no soltó a su madre **hasta que no** lo arrebataron de su falda, y por un instante sintióse suspendido en el vacío, yendo a parar al interior de una lancha apretada de pasajeros pobres.*

Lo que me gustaría saber es:

- ¿Desde cuándo se viene escribiendo en español "hasta que no" cuando debería ser "hasta que" o "mientras no"? El último ejemplo mencionado es de 1896, aunque he visto otros en textos del siglo XVIII.
- ¿Recoge la RAE esta peculiaridad en su gramática? Si es así, ¿la da como algo aceptado o aconseja evitar su uso al menos en la expresión escrita?

Comment: Hay algo parecido en alemán.

Answer (score 2):

Sólo puedo responder tu segunda pregunta.

En su Diccionario de Dudas y Dificultades de la Lengua Española, el académico Manuel Seco dice, en relación con la preposición *hasta*:

> 3. La preposición *hasta*, precediendo a la conjunción *que*, introduce proposiciones temporales: *Leeré hasta que me canse; Todos se quedaron hasta que se acabó el vino.* Cuando el verbo principal va acompañado de una negación, es frecuente que se presente un *no* expletivo en la proposición: *Ninguno se marchó hasta que NO se acabó el vino.* Aunque es un uso normal en España, sería deseable omitir ese *no* (que carece de todo sentido negativo) a fin de evitar la posible interpretación equivocada del mensaje (v. Cuervo, “Apuntaciones”, § 448). También la ausencia del *no* es normal: *Ninguno se marchó hasta que se acabó el vino.*

Si bien el modo en que lo explica resulta algo confuso, Seco quiere decir que ambas formas, con “no” y sin “no”, son usadas, aunque la segunda es preferible. No dice que “no” sea incorrecto, sino redundante, tal vez emparentado – esta apreciación es mía – con el doble negativo típico del español: “No tomé nada de vino.” Ahora bien, cuando el verbo principal es afirmativo, puede utilizarse *no* en la proposición: “Festejaremos hasta que las velas no ardan” (o sea, mientras las velas ardan).

Bajo *tanto*, Seco dice algo similar:

> 4. *Hasta tanto que*, locución conjuntiva, equivale a *hasta que* (HASTA. 3) y, como esta, puede ir seguida de un *no* expletivo; en este último caso a veces se reduce a *hasta tanto*: *Yo tampoco lío el primero ... hasta tanto no fumes tú también.* (Liar: Formar un cigarrillo envolviendo la picadura en el papel de fumar.)

Comment: Tu apreciación de que el no expletivo puede estar emparentado con la doble negación también se me ocurrió a mí. Es una posibilidad interesante.

Comment: Probablemente por el mismo motivo que aparece un *no* redundante, a veces desaparece el que correspondería: yo prácticamente siempre escucho *«(Festejaremos) hasta que las velas ardan»*, sin negación.